# What should I factor in when moving from a 50/34T to a 53/39T

Tags: road-bike

I have a 11-32 cassette.

I'll be looking to do this for short 30km rides and long 100km rides on the weekend. the 30km rides have a few hills, nothing major, whilst the longer ride is generally quite flat.

Other than changing the chain to compensate for wear as well as factoring in the larger diameter of the new crank what else should i consider?

Apologies, I am very new to cycling and not sure where else to ask or where to look for information.

Comment: You will need to to have a longer chain and you will need to adjust your front derailleur because it will have to be in a slightly higher position to accommodate the larger chain rings.

Comment: Although a 50-34 is normally high enough gearing unless you have very fast downhills.

Comment: @PaddyLivingstone great thanks, other than slightly harder uphills what other disadvantages of higher tooth no. on the crank?

Comment: No other disadvantages. But the larger gearing can be a very big disadvantage up hills. In the smallest gear that you will have with the bigger chainrings (39, 32) then if you drop below twelve and a half Km/h then you will only be doing about 75 cadence which I find is a slower cadence than I find comfortable. Whereas with the compact chain rings you will still be doing about 95 cadence. It's up to you and how fast you can go whether the larger chainrings are a disadvantage uphill

Comment: Or to put it another way: If you can maintain a speed of approximately 13km/h or higher up all the hills then the large chainrings have no disadvantage. On the other end of things, if you don't normally go faster than about 60Km/h then the smaller chain rings have no disadvantage.

Comment: It seems like teeth number is also personal preference? With these points you've added I see it as a challenge on how much better/higher power output I can gain in the long run

Comment: @PaddyLivingstone

Comment: It definitely involves quite a bit of personal preference. Faster riders use higher gears so they don't end up spinning out their gears. I currently have a 39-54, 11-28 on my race bike because I normally race sprint triathlons(20Km cycle). But what you have to avoid is "grinding", which means struggling to push a gear that's too big and so only having a slow cadence. I have a spare 50-30 chain set for my race bike, and my other bikes have similar lower geared set ups so I don't end up grinding

Comment: If you grind you get left behind, if you spin you win.

Comment: @PaddyLivingstone ah yea I've read that higher cadence on a lower gear is far more beneficial for the rider over a longer period of time. Thanks for all the advice and personal notes as well. I think I will go for the 53/39 and just force my body into this.

I have a second question as its 11 speed 12-32 cassette. I'll be getting a new chain, either preference for a 114 or a 118 chain link? (these are the two numbers the chain I would like comes in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49979/discussion-between-curious-and-paddy-livingstone).

Comment: You will usually have to cut the chain to length using a chain breaker tool, they are not expensive so I would recommend getting one. The length is determined by all sorts of things including chainstay length and derailleur cage length so it's hard to tell what size you will need. If your current chain fits well with the compact crankset then as you are increasing the biggest chainring by 3 teeth then you will need the chain to be 4 links longer for the larger crankset (chains can only change by an even number of links)

Comment: @PaddyLivingstone great thanks, I think i'll take it into the LBS so i can ask further questions, soak up as much information in the quickest time rather than trolling through the net. Thanks for all your input, have a merry christmas!

Comment: I ride a lot of climbs, and I would not give up my granny gear for anything, On 26/28 I can just about spin up a flight of stairs.   If you do any climbs, try them again but only in the current big chain-ring and see how it feels to run out of gears.

Comment: @Criggie the new small chainring of 39 teeth is way smaller than 50 you are suggesting.

Answer (score 6):

Changing from a 34 to a 39 chainring is roughly the same as changing from a 32 to a 28 max rear sprocket.  In other words, you'd lose your lowest gear.

Comment: You've made it seem so simple, is this really all to it? IF so it  doesnt seem to be that big of a change when the forums make it appear so

Comment: 34 / 39 = 0.872.  0.872 x 32 = 27.9.  An SRAM PG-1130 11-32 has sprockets of 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 22, 25, 28, 32 teeth.

Comment: I have the 105 5800 11 speed  11-32

Answer (score 3):

The main thing to think about is matching your drive train to the potential terrain, and ensuring that you have a gearing inches that matches your normal setup. Your biggest "miss" is going to be on the low end, so if you tend to spend a lot of time in the 34T chainring up front, you may want to rethink the decision.

The [gear inches tool](http://www.bikecalc.com/gear_inches) at BikeCalc is a good one to play with to get an idea of what I mean.

For example, with your 34T and in the 11T cog in the back, you have gear inches of 81.3. The closest you'll come to that with a 39T is with a 13T in the back, and even then you are a couple of inches "off". That may make a difference to you, or it may not. (If you find yourself "hunting" between a couple of gears, where one is too easy and the other is too hard, that's a gap in your gearing that you need to look at). I had that a lot on my tri bike until I got a cassette that included a 15T rear rather than one that went 14-16 and skipped 15.

So in one sense, it won't make your riding any easier or more difficult, it's just how you match the gears to the ride. Flat ride? Go big. Really hilly? Gear for the smaller side. If you get to the point where you can switch your own rings and chain(s), then you can mix/match gearing to your hearts content.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what the motivation for the swap is.  Do you find 50-11 not high enough?  Swapping to 53/39 should work fine, probably without any change of chain.  You only need another 3/4 link, so you might need one more.  50/11 is quite high already, so many would suggest you just need to learn to spin faster. As others have said, you lose your current lowest gear.  Do you use it now?  If a compact is not cool, a 53/39 will solve that problem.